# Auto move files from a USB flash drive to system drive

Tags: bash, usb, automation

At my school, I use A USB flash drive to store my data and bring it home. But when I am home, I would like to integrate the new data from the USB flash drive into my personal filesystem.

There are two main directories in which I work. I would like to copy everything new to these directories.

I thought about bash but I don't know much about it.

So I hope to get some ideas and/or resources that could help to develop a solution. Hand copying is time consuming and error prone.

Comment: What OS are you on? Linux? macOS? You mention Bash and you could easily write a Bash shel script that syncs from the from the USB flash drive to your system and the other way around. But unfortunately, we don’t do software recommendations her nor do “from scratch” scripting. Read up on how Rsync works [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories).

Answer (score 1):

I you use windows you could set up a task using task scheduler, or autoruns, which is a program from the system internals suite of software from Microsoft. It will allow you to schedule the computer to do basically anything, even posting to social media automatically. You could set up a task that would run a script to sync the usb drive files with another directory.